# Updating database values using ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form and it has `radio` buttons that a user must click to increement a value in the database but I click the `radio` button and nothing happens in the database heres my form code:

```
<form  id="myform" name="myform" method="post">
<div class="radio show-options">
    <li><label id="l_security"><input type="radio" id="r_security" name="weekend" value="security" />Security</label> (<label id="c_security">0</label>)</li>
</div>
<div class="radio show-options">
    <li><label id="l_manager"><input type="radio" id="r_manager" name="weekend" value="manager" />Manager</label> (<label id="c_manager">0</label>)</li>
</div>
<div class="radio show-options">
    <li><label id="l_cleaner"><input type="radio" id="r_cleaner" name="weekend" value="cleaner" />Cleaner</label> (<label id="c_cleaner">0</label>)</li>
</div>
</form>
```

here the script for the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastClicked = '';

    function getTotals() {
        // function to get click counts as JSON from helper page
        // expects get_count.php to be in same directory level

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_count.php",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(xhr, status, msg) {
                alert("Failed to get click counts: " + msg);
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // loop through JSON variables, assign to count labels
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                var tmp = "#c_" + key;
                $(tmp).text(value);
            });
        });
    }

    function processClick(obj) {
        // function to increment click count via ajax
        // expects increment_count.php to be in same directory level
        if(lastClicked != obj.val()) { // don't count clicks on currently active radio button
            lastClicked = obj.val(); // set currently clicked radio button to this one

            var qs = "weekend=" + obj.val(); // set query string value

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "increment_count.php",
                data: qs,
                error: function(xhr, status, msg) {
                    alert("Failed to process click count: " + msg);
                }
            })
            .done(function() {
                getTotals(); // update totals on successful processing
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        getTotals(); // get click totals on initial page load

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // add click incrementing event handler to all radio buttons on page
            $('input:radio').click(function() {
                processClick($(this));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is get_count.php

```
<?php
require('db_connect.php');

// get new count totals, pass as JSON
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee") or die('Cannot get updated click counts');
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    $out = "{ ";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $out .= "\"$row[name]\" : $row[leave], ";
    }
    $out = substr($out, 0, strlen($out) - 2);
    $out .= " }";

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo $out;
}
```

and here is increment_count.php

```
<?php
require('db_connect.php');

// if this is a postback ...
if(isset($_GET['weekend'])) {
    // create array of acceptable values
    $ok = array('security', 'manager', 'cleaner');
    // if we have an acceptable value for position_name ...
    if(in_array($_GET['weekend'], $ok)) {
        // update the counter for that position
        $q = mysql_query("UPDATE employee SET leave = leave + 3 WHERE name = '".$_GET['weekend'] . "'") or die ("Error updating count for " . $_GET['weekend']);
    }
}
```

the leave value in the `employee` table is not increased

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is your PHP script successfully called?

Comment: my script is succesfully called. the database value is not incremented yet when I use the same code to just increment just another dummy table for testing purposes it works yet it dosnt work on my main table.

Comment: Hi, it looks like every part of app is correct. Do you receive die() message from increment_count.php?

Comment: No I do not recieve a die() message and when I use the same code to just increment just another dummy table for testing purposes it works yet it dosnt work on my main table.

Comment: @MaqhaweSimelane first of all replace `$q = mysql_query...` with `return mysql_query` to have a knowladge whats going on. I have test your code. If you send proper value in query string (`"weekend=" + obj.val()`) the only problem can be with database connection. Are you sure that `increment_count.php` has db_conn access?

Comment: Just open error reporting to all. then you will able to find the errors or warnings.

Comment: Do you receive `die()` message from `increment_count.php` script?

Comment: There is no die() message I recieve and db_conn is connected because when I use the same codes just to increment a counter of colours in a table works but doesnt work in my employee table @WebHQ..

Comment: Ok, please use Firebug or other developer tools and post GET request that you send to script

Comment: Thank you @WebHQ it now works after having return mysql_query

Comment: please consider to use `json_encode(array('code' => 'OK', 'message' => 'OK'))` as a response ;) and not send direst messages from PDO or die() messages. 
Good Luck!